How to scale conditionally using sklearn minmaxscaler
I have a column that has positive, 0 and negative values. Rows with 0 values constitute 90% of dataframe. I want to scale this column but without touching 0 value rows. Only those rows that have non zero value should be scaled between -1 to 1 according to the range of max & min values in that column.
Is this possible or I need to first separate out non 0 rows in another df and then do scaling there and them merge with parent df ?

create new df with non 0 values
drop those rows from parent df
apply scaling on new df
concat parent df with the dp from step 3

Is this the best way to do ?

Yes, your approach is a good way to handle this, but it can be simplified without creating separate dataframes. You can achieve the same result by applying a scaling function conditionally, directly on the column, without modifying the rows with 0 values. Hope this might help you.
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': [-5, 0, 2, -3, 0, 4, 7, 0, -1]
})

# Create a mask for non-zero values
non_zero_mask = df['col'] != 0

# Separate the non-zero values
non_zero_values = df.loc[non_zero_mask, 'col'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Apply MinMaxScaler to scale between -1 and 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(non_zero_values)

# Replace the scaled values back into the original dataframe, keeping 0s intact
df.loc[non_zero_mask, 'col'] = scaled_values

print(df)

